# Affirm order confirmation email - Payment Method for Affirm show as a Guest

Tags: guest-checkout, order-confirmation, affirm

Payment Method for Affirm show as a Guest, however the billing and shipping info show the name of the customer - Payapal and CC payment do not have this issue. Magento ver. 2.4.6-p3. I am using the magento default email template. I did update the guest templet, basically i copied the new order confirmation email template and pasted it into  guest template and enabled it- still no luck - only affirm payments still shows up as guest. is there solution for this?